# Rich:Columns - FilterBy

Tags: richfaces, filtering, richdatatable

Good morning!!

I have a dynamic datatable and I'm using Columns of Richfaces, but when I assign the value to FilterBy, it does not work.
Can anyone help me?
Woe is my code ..

```
<rich:dataTable id="dtAtendimento" value="#{CadastroAtendimentoTecnico.listaAtendimento}" var="atendimento">
    <rich:columns index="index" value="#{CadastroAtendimentoTecnico.listaCampos}" var="column" filterBy="#{column.nomeAtributo}" filterEvent="onKeyUp">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="#{column.label}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{atendimento[column.nomeAtributo]}"/>
    </rich:columns>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: as a sidenote - it is advisable to use English in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am Brazilian and I do what I can with translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `sortBy="#{column.nomeAtributo}"`  and `sortOrder` to `rich:columns` it will work.
I came to know that we have such problems on early version.
Please try RF 3.2.1. I think it should solve the problem otherwise.

Comment: did not work
the examples I have seen, the id of the columns is concatenate with index, is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you are using the wrong attribute in filterBy. You want to use nesting to specify where to find the element to sort on. Something like `#{atendimento(column.nomeAtributo)}`, but I am not in a place I can test it. What this essentially does is evaluate the name of the column and then calls the getter with the same name off of your row object `atendimento`. Sorry if the nesting syntax doesn't work, but I think nesting is your answer.

*If `#{atendimento[column.nomeAtributo]}` works to print the value then that is what you want, but I would only expect it to work if nomeAtributo is an integer for array referencing.*

Answer (score 0):

I've come across another issue with filterBy which can cause problems. We had the filterBy working on entities in a certain business state (active, expired etc) but not in others. The state of the entity had nothing to do with the actual filter value.

When I used a filterMethod and did the filtering on the backing bean it worked fine. It turned out that filterBy submits the whole form while on my inputText for the filterMethod I used ajaxSingle. A validation failed when you submitted that form in total but the validation error was swallowed.